# EF Core inherited class data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm writing a web app using Core 2.0 MVC.  With the help of EF I'm trying to create (code first) models to model the database so I can automate the whole db creation process using migration.

My issue, I'm using a third party library to interact with an API (this library was built specifically to interact with this API) but the data that the API returns I'd like to store in a db using the same schema as the class from the library.

As an example
*Third party library*

```
 public class PersonDetails
 {
     public long PersonID { get; set; }
     public string PersonName { get; set; }
 }
```

If i try to create a migration for this class it complains about no primary key being set, I'm unable to modify this class.  Is there a way that I can set the [Key] attribute for PersonID from an inherited class or something similar?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys#fluent-api

Comment: Thanks for that I'll take a look.